# Can we add/change scope with a plugin in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: python, sublimetext3

In a custom *.sublime-syntax file, I have this:

```
- match: '(\d+)/(\d+)x (.+)$'
  captures:
    1: constant.numeric.owned.items_tracker
    2: constant.numeric.needed.items_tracker
    3: variable.description.items_tracker
```

I would like to set capture 3 scope to `variable.description.done.items_tracker` instead if capture 1 is greater than capture 2

I think is not possible to do this in sublime-syntax ; so, can I do this with python in a plugin and how?

Comment: `sublime-syntax` can only highlight your code; if you want to modify the file you need a plugin to do so. A plugin can edit an open file however you like, but it's unclear from your question when or how you want something like this to happen.

Comment: I edited and clarity what I want (I think)

Answer (score 0):

In Sublime, syntax definitions are the only way to apply scopes, and the scopes are applied by using regular expression matches such as the ones outlined in your question.

The Syntax facility doesn't have any sort of direct "conditional" logic that would allow it to take a programmatic action like converting the matches to integers and then compare them and do something different.

Additionally although a plugin can modify the source of a file at will, it can't apply scopes; that is strictly the purview of the syntax definition itself.

As such, what you want to do is not directly possible in the general case. A potential workaround might be to have as many rules as there are combinations of numeric values, but that's not practical unless the total range of values and the spreads between them is very small.